# Can "It mattered..." be rewritten like this "...was important"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Can I rewrite the sentences in bold like this: "**Not whether the parts of the system functioned, or even existed was important, but only that certain people, for a certain period of time, believed that they did was important**"

> Instead of serving intended rational purposes, modern management techniques contributed to a saga that built external legitimacy and support and kept critics and legislators at bay. The myth afforded breathing space for work to go forward and elevated participants’ spirits and self-confidence. The Polaris story demonstrates the virtues of drama in engaging the attention and appreciation of both internal and external audiences: “An alchemist’s combination of whirling computers, bright-colored charts, and fast-talking public relations officers gave the Special Projects Office a truly effective management system. **It mattered not whether the parts of the system functioned, or even existed. It mattered only that certain people, for a certain period of time, believed that they did”(Sapolsky, 1972, p. 129)**.

Source: [Reframing Organizations: Artistry, Choice, and Leadership](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=lCAlDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=Instead+of+serving+intended+rational+purposes,+modern+management+techniques+contributed+to+a+saga+that+built+external+legitimacy+and+support+and+kept+critics+and+legislators+at+bay.+The+myth+afforded+breathing+space+for+work+to+go+forward+and+elevated+participants%E2%80%99+spirits+and+self-confidence.+The+Polaris+story+demonstrates+the+virtues+of+drama+in+engaging+the+attention+and+appreciation+of+both+internal+and+external+audiences:+%E2%80%9CAn+alchemist%E2%80%99s+combination+of+whirling+computers,+bright-colored+charts,+and+fast-talking+public+relations+officers+gave+the+Special+Projects+Office+a+truly+effective+management+system.+It+mattered+not+whether+the+parts+of+the+system+functioned,+or+even+existed.+It+mattered+only+that+certain+people,+for+a+certain+period+of+time,+believed+that+they+did%E2%80%9D(Sapolsky,+1972,+p.+129).&source=bl&ots=uRuZ4dnCLZ&sig=ACfU3U1lfgU_mmfM8s-ev4XnuXjScJqCww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHjZeS9fnhAhUaPXAKHYYUBmkQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Instead%20of%20serving%20intended%20rational%20purposes%2C%20modern%20management%20techniques%20contributed%20to%20a%20saga%20that%20built%20external%20legitimacy%20and%20support%20and%20kept%20critics%20and%20legislators%20at%20bay.%20The%20myth%20afforded%20breathing%20space%20for%20work%20to%20go%20forward%20and%20elevated%20participants%E2%80%99%20spirits%20and%20self-confidence.%20The%20Polaris%20story%20demonstrates%20the%20virtues%20of%20drama%20in%20engaging%20the%20attention%20and%20appreciation%20of%20both%20internal%20and%20external%20audiences%3A%20%E2%80%9CAn%20alchemist%E2%80%99s%20combination%20of%20whirling%20computers%2C%20bright-colored%20charts%2C%20and%20fast-talking%20public%20relations%20officers%20gave%20the%20Special%20Projects%20Office%20a%20truly%20effective%20management%20system.%20It%20mattered%20not%20whether%20the%20parts%20of%20the%20system%20functioned%2C%20or%20even%20existed.%20It%20mattered%20only%20that%20certain%20people%2C%20for%20a%20certain%20period%20of%20time%2C%20believed%20that%20they%20did%E2%80%9D(Sapolsky%2C%201972%2C%20p.%20129).&f=false)

Comment: -1 I have mentioned repeatedly that you should not simply paste long URLs into your questions (it's terrible formatting), but use hyperlinks instead. I've also pointed you to [documentation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) on how to do that. (At first, I edited these questions for you.)

Answer (score 1):

*Just like that?* Literally "Not whether the parts of the system functioned, or even existed was important, but only that certain people, for a certain period of time, believed that they did was important"?

That's not a sentence.  It's just a very long noun-phrase.

Comment: The verb: "was important".

Answer (score 0):

Your verb comes way too late in your sentence, as Malvolio said, your rewrite doesn't read like a sentence. I understand that "It mattered not ... " is a little artistic, or idiomatic, and hard to understand. If I needed to rewrite the paragraph using "important" instead of "mattered" I might write something like this:

> ... It (was not important) whether the parts of the system functioned, or even
>   existed. It (was only important) that certain people, for a certain period of
>   time, believed that they did ...

Since it was a direct quote, I put the pieces I changed in parenthesis to show an edit was made to the original wording.